# Why doesn't Hotspot JIT perform loop unrolling for long counters?

Tags: java, compiler-optimization, jit, jvm-hotspot, loop-unrolling

I just read the Java Magazine article [Loop Unrolling](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/loop-unrolling). There the authors demonstrate that simple `for` loops with an `int` counter are compiled with loop unrolling optimization:

```java
private long intStride1()
{
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i += 1)
    {
        sum += data[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

However, they follow by showing that everything changes by switching the counter type to `long`:

```java
private long longStride1()
{
    long sum = 0;
    for (long l = 0; l < MAX; l++)
    {
        sum += data[(int) l];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

This changes the output assembly by:

1. Introducing Safepoints
2. Not performing unrolling

This has an effect of drastically reducing throughput performance.

Why doesn't 64 bit HotSpot VM perform loop unrolling for `long` counters? Why does the second case need safepoints, but the first one doesn't?

Comment: [This has been already fixed in JDK 16](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8223051)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since JDK 16, HotSpot JVM supports loop unrolling and other optimizations on loops with a 64-bit counter.

The description of [JDK-8223051](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8223051) answers your both questions:

> Many core loop transformations apply to counted loops, which are those
> with a calculated trip count. Transformations include unrolling,
> iteration range splitting (array RCE), and strip mining (JDK-8186027).
> The optimizer performs many complicated pattern matches to detect and
> transform counted loop.
>
> Most or all of these pattern matches and transformations apply to
> loops with 32-bit control variables and arithmetic. This makes sense
> as long as bulk operations apply only to Java arrays, since those
> arrays can only span a 31-bit index range. Newer APIs for larger
> blocks of bulk data will introduce 64-bit indexes, such as Panama's
> native arrays and (possibly) range-expanded byte buffers. Under the
> hood, the Unsafe API routinely works with 64-bit addresses and address
> arithmetic. Loops which work on such data structures naturally use
> 64-bit values, either as direct Java longs, or as wrapped cursor
> structure with incrementing long components (Panama pointers).
>
> There needs to be a story for transforming such long-running loops.
> This RFE is a request for that story.
>
> A complicating factor is that sometimes counted loops have no
> safepoints, on the assumption that the largest possible iteration
> (across 32 bits of dynamic range) won't cause the JVM's safepoint
> mechanism to malfunction due to a non-responsive thread stuck in such
> a counted loop. This assumption is invalid in the 64-bit case.
> Luckily, we have a (relatively new) optimization which can address
> this problem, by strip-mining a single very long running loop into a
> sequence (outer loop) of loops of with appropriately bounded trip
> counts.

Answer (score 0):

That’s because of tracing possible integer overflows. It’s easy to catch integer overflow when casting int to long and check against min/max int, but there’s no bigger type than long on most platforms.
But since JDK 16 long loops are supported.